# Recursive type bound - semantic

Tags: java, oop, generics

I try to understand what is a practical difference between:

```
interface Wrapper<T extends Wrapper<T>>
```

and

```
interface Wrapper<T extends Wrapper>
```

They seem to behave same - in what cases the second one allows more than the first one?

Comment: TL;DR: `T extends Wrapper` has a raw type, `T extends Wrapper<T>` doesn't have a raw type.